# Ethereum Solidity Contract - Mocha timeouts at web3.eth.Contract send() method

Tags: mocha.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am currently learning Solidity and trying to build a simple contract. I am also trying to use the Mocha framework to test the smart contract before deploying. The test code is per below:

```
const assert = require("assert");
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const { interface, bytecode } = require("../compile");

const provider = ganache.provider();
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  // Use one of those accounts to deploy the contract
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({
      data: bytecode,
      arguments: ["Hi there!"]
    })
    .send({
      from: accounts[0],
      gas: "1000000"
    });

});

describe("Inbox", () => {
  it("deploys a contract", () => {
    console.log(inbox);
  });
});
```

The test fails and timeouts:

```
> mocha

  Inbox
    1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract"


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I noticed that the test passes if I comment out the send() argument:

```
// .send({
//   from: accounts[0],
//   gas: "1000000"
// });
```

So the issue must be with using this method. Not sure if it is an async issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by downgrading web3 to `1.0.0-beta.37`. Seems like version `1.0.0-beta.51` is buggy.